# How do I use DI in lower layers that aren't exposed to the UI layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do I setup DI with the below structure so the UI layer doesn't know about or reference the Data layer project. Where do I register `IUserRepo` for `UserRepo` or `UserTestRepo`. Right now everything needs to be registered in the WebApi's startup.

### Project structure

- WebApi (UI Layer) - Uses the business layer's services but shouldn't know/access the repos.
- Services (Business Layer) - Uses the data layer's repos and exposes IUserService, IProductRepo, etc
- DataAccess (Data Layer) - Uses EF Core to access the DB and only exposes IUserRepo, IProductRepo, etc

Comment: This question asks a very basic question about a 3-tier solution using dependency injection. Firstly, what research have you done, what have you attempted to do and where are you at now? Let's see some code.

Comment: 3 projects deployed in 3 servers and contact via api with each other?

Comment: @TinyWang DataAccess and Services projects are libraries referenced by the WebApi project.